# How would power leveled nobility influence recourse for tyranny?

Tags: society, politics, super-powers

In real life, governments are mostly beholden to the rich, but if they crush the middle and lower classes too much, there will be an uprising eventually. But what if the very upper classes (<1%) held the secrets of magic/cultivation, which make it impossible for any number of peasants to overcome them physically? For instance, using [Dragon Ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Ball) as reference, no matter how many regular humans felt oppressed by Son Goku, they could never overcome him. Being overthrown would require Son Goku to make enemies of other powerful beings like Vegeta or the androids.

In my setting, mages are basically assassination proof in that regard. The local mages/lords are less beholden to the common folk compared to their fellow mage lords than in the case of even the worst feudal lords in our own timeline, since mages are the only ones who can threaten them.

Can the local peasantry just make life so difficult for the lower ranking mages (maybe by destroying property or not producing goods) that the lower mage lords (Krillin level) bring the peasants' issues up at court? Really, irritating one of these mages would just be throwing your life away, so I'm not sure it would be possible, but there doesn't seem to be historical precedent, since we are ruled by humans and AI. Any potential methods or countermeasures would be appreciated.

Comment: I appreciate that you accepted my answer, but trust me: 25 minutes is not enough for getting the best answer. Give a chance to other users to contribute and then pick the one which mostly solve your problem. That's why we usually advice to wait at least 24 hours before accepting one answer.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. Sorry; still new.

Comment: Let's look at it in Dragonball terms: There's as much air between Son-Goku and Krilin as is between Krilin and any normal human. He might be the least powerful of the combat-cast of Dragonball, but he still infinitely more powerful than the most powerful non-combat-cast.

Comment: But Goku *likes* to eat real food. He has loved ones who are not as powerful as he is.

Comment: at least historically, there some peasants that do stop producing goods as a way to protest, especially regarding farm goods, though it can also affect their own life and get even more worse for the peasants life style or wellbeing, so its quite a double edge sword, and its up to how stubborn and how well their attrition is to tick the nobility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ruling class is really untouchable, the answer depends only on how enlightened/egalitarian they are.

Human history is, for the most part, the history of oppression. Whenever ruling class has a leverage on the lower class, they usually use that leverage to the fullest extent. Two factors are limiting that: revolutions and inefficiency. Revolution is either upending the class order, or scares the ruling class enough to offer significant concessions. Inefficiency is slowly putting old-style economy (ex. slavery, serfdom) out of business, and eventually, ruling class either makes concessions or diminishes into obscurity.

In your world, revolutions are not an option. Inefficiency, on the other hand, can be a very viable tool for the lower class. Explicit destruction or sabotage would be dealt with harshly, but creeping decay cannot be fixed by using force.

Thus, eventually, the ruling class will see the advantage of empowering the lower class - although this process can take a very long time.

Essentially, **the answer is "yes"** - just not right away.

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer to your question boils down to "what is the difference between a consumable good and an asset?"

Take a company with a few thousand employees. For their day to day operation, they need a lot of supporting material and infrastructure: buildings, desk, IT, stationery and so on.

Buildings and IT are maintained, while paper or pens are used until good and then thrown away. What dictates the difference? Simply put, it's much more convenient to buy a new pen than to fix a damaged/broken one. On the other hand, building a new office is often more expensive/difficult than taking good care of an existing one.

Similar approach in your situation: the mages are unbeatable, but if they want to survive they need to rely on the output of the work of the masses. Do they have a steady/easy resupply of that "good"?

If they have it, then the masses are like the pens in my example: use them until they are good, then throw them away for new ones.
If they don't have it, then put effort in some "maintenance".

It's not a matter of making life difficult for the upper ones, it's a matter of keeping the entire society structure in place.

Comment: Makes sense. The mages in this case actually don't even need to eat to survive, but they would have to see society as an investment, or be overthrown by the mages that don't want to live in a dung heap after staughtering all the muck rakers.

Comment: Just to add to this answer as I cant quite get the words right for my own answer. a CEO owns the business, but more often than not doesn't do everything themselves. Your mages need to delegate some work, most likely the boring stuff

Answer (score 1):

#### Unionization

Strip the magic away from the question but keep the power, and your question looks basically the same as the situation at several large non-union companies; Mcdonalds (America), Wallmart, Amazon, etc. disposable workers toil for survival while a wealthy powerful elite is enriched by their labour.

Just like in your story, people who complain are throwing their lives away - although in the modern world that means food stamps and homeless shelters rather than direct death by angry Mage.

The solution is the same too - people decide to unite first, and then complain, work slow, strike, etc. The mage holds the secrets of magic, the boss writes the paycheques, but that power is nothing compared to all workers uniting for their common good. If the upper class kills them all, they stop being the upper class - Son Goku now has to make their own food.

Comment: But SonGoku does have no need for food, shelter and such, he can just magic it up and feed on mana...

Comment: @Trish if he has no need for anything from the people then he has nothing to gain from enslaving them in the first place. But if eating real food is easier, or anyone he cares about needs to eat real food, or there is any benefit provided at all by the masses, then those masses United have the power to take it away.

Answer (score 1):

So the idea here is that the mages are competing with each other and using the common people as resources to do that.  That means that they probably care about how productive the people they oppress are in order to make them look good.

So if mage A treats his people horribly they can't stop him.  But if mages B,C, and D treat their people better and as a result they have more stuff and look better at court and look down on mage A that could inspire A to listen to his people.